# Merge two columns by mapping column names to row values of another column

Tags: pandas

Is it possible to merge two columns by mapping column names to values in antoher column?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 1, 2, 3],
        "label": ["foo", "moo", "foo", "moo"],
        "foo.foo": ["foo", "foo", "foo", np.nan],
        "moo.moo": ["moo", "moo", np.nan, np.nan],
    }
)
```

expected result:

```
id label foo.moo 
1  foo   foo     
1  moo   moo     
2  foo   foo
```

Comment: What exactly is the logic here?

Comment: question is not clear. Can you explain how are the column names derived

Comment: Sorry for my bad question. The logic would be if df["label"]== foo, and df["foo.foo"] is not NaN, then merge to the new column df["foo.moo"] same goes for "moo.moo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if this works for you

```
df['foo_moo_updated'] = df['foo.moo'].mask(df.label=='foo',df['foo.foo'])
df[~df['foo_moo_updated'].isnull()]

    id  label   foo.foo foo.moo foo_moo_updated
0   1   foo foo moo foo
1   1   moo foo moo moo
2   2   foo foo NaN foo
```